# Why does getenv returns NULL here?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    for (int i = 0; envp[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%d.%s\n", i , envp[i]);
    }

    char *aux;

    if (getenv(envp[0]) != NULL) {
        aux = getenv(envp[0]);
    } else {
        printf("NULL\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to print a specific value of an enviorment variable but getenv returns null and i dont know why.When
i say getenv("USER") for example it works fine

Comment: If you look at the output from the `printf("%d.%s\n", i , envp[i]);` calls it should be obvious why `getenv(envp[0])` returns `NULL` -- what is the 'value' of `envp[0]`?

Comment: Your programs happily prints environment variables with [online GDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)

Comment: isnt the value: /bin/bash

Comment: `envp[0]` in my system is `"ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData"` not `"ALLUSERSPROFILE"`. So the `envp[0]` isn't a valid key for `getenv()`.

Comment: Re. `"isnt the value: /bin/bash"`: ...or is it more like `SHELL=/bin/bash`?

Comment: One more datapoint for me `4.SHELL=/bin/bash` and `0.NVM_RC_VERSION=`

Comment: oh i understand ,so my argument in getenv is SHELL=/bin/bash which is not valid.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The call to `getenv(envp[0])` returns `NULL` because you are passing a string that contains the key *and its value*. Just pass the key.

For example, `envp[0]` in my system is

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
```

not

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:

> The getenv() function searches the environment list to find the
> environment variable name, and returns a pointer to the
> corresponding value string.

*"Re: isnt the value: /bin/bash?"*

You answered your own question.
`getenv` searches for a variable name, and returns it's value. But you passed it `envp[0]`, which contains both the name and it's value, hence the `NULL`.

`"SHELL"` is a valid argument to `getenv`, while `SHELL=/bin/bash` is not.